# Joining two of the same queries but from different schemas

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I am running a query in Tableau to pull email data from a few different tables. Right now, this works and puts out results. Data is in redshift.

QUERY 1

```
WITH activities AS (
SELECT A.lead_id, A.primary_attribute_value_id, T.name, A.activity_date
FROM marketo_sc.lead_activities A, marketo_sc.lead_activity_types T
WHERE T.name IN ('Send Email', 'Email Delivered', 'Open Email', 'Click Email', 'Unsubscribe Email') AND A.activity_type_id=T.id 
GROUP BY A.lead_id, A.primary_attribute_value_id, T.name, A.activity_date
),
totals AS (
SELECT A.name AS activity_t, E.subject AS subject, E.name AS email, A.activity_date , count(*)
FROM activities A, marketo_sc.emails E
WHERE A.primary_attribute_value_id = E.id AND E.name LIKE '%Bounceback%'
GROUP BY email, activity_t, subject, A.activity_date
)
SELECT email, subject, 'sc' as program, activity_date,
sum(case when activity_t='Send Email' then count else 0 end) AS sent,
sum(case when activity_t='Email Delivered' then count else 0 end) AS delivered,
sum(case when activity_t='Open Email' then count else 0 end) AS opened,
sum(case when activity_t='Click Email' then count else 0 end) AS clicked,
sum(case when activity_t='Unsubscribe Email' then count else 0 end) AS unsubscribed
FROM totals
GROUP BY email, subject, activity_date
```

However, I have another table that has the exact same setup

QUERY 2

```
WITH tgactivities AS (
SELECT A.lead_id, A.primary_attribute_value_id, T.name, A.activity_date
FROM marketo_tg.lead_activities A, marketo_tg.lead_activity_types T
WHERE T.name IN ('Send Email', 'Email Delivered', 'Open Email', 'Click Email', 'Unsubscribe Email') AND A.activity_type_id=T.id 
GROUP BY A.lead_id, A.primary_attribute_value_id, T.name, A.activity_date
),
tgtotals AS (
SELECT A.name AS activity_t, E.subject AS subject, E.name AS email, A.activity_date , count(*)
FROM tgactivities A, marketo_tg.emails E
WHERE A.primary_attribute_value_id = E.id AND E.name LIKE '%Bounceback%'
GROUP BY email, activity_t, subject, A.activity_date
)
SELECT email, subject, 'tg' as program, activity_date,
sum(case when activity_t='Send Email' then count else 0 end) AS sent,
sum(case when activity_t='Email Delivered' then count else 0 end) AS delivered,
sum(case when activity_t='Open Email' then count else 0 end) AS opened,
sum(case when activity_t='Click Email' then count else 0 end) AS clicked,
sum(case when activity_t='Unsubscribe Email' then count else 0 end) AS unsubscribed
FROM tgtotals
GROUP BY email, subject, activity_date
```

I tried to do UNION in between them but I got a syntax error

[Amazon][RedShift ODBC] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WITH" LINE 26: WITH tgactivities AS ( ^

Any Help or ideas on why this can be happening?

Comment: Just write them both to temp tables and union the temp tables

Comment: @DanielMarcus what would that look like?

Comment: Does below work for you?

Comment: @DanielMarcus when executing just that query for 1 table, im now getting "[Amazon][RedShift ODBC] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 9: SELECT A.name AS activity_t, E.subject AS subject, E.name ... ^"

Comment: OK see edited below

Comment: Nope :/ "[Amazon][RedShift ODBC] (30) Error occurred while trying to execute a query: ERROR: column "count" does not exist in b"

Comment: OK please try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT email, subject, 'tg' as program, activity_date,
sum(case when activity_t='Send Email' then [count] else 0 end) AS sent,
sum(case when activity_t='Email Delivered' then [count] else 0 end) AS delivered,
sum(case when activity_t='Open Email' then [count] else 0 end) AS opened,
sum(case when activity_t='Click Email' then [count] else 0 end) AS clicked,
sum(case when activity_t='Unsubscribe Email' then [count] else 0 end) AS unsubscribed
FROM (SELECT A.name AS activity_t, E.subject AS subject, E.name AS email, A.activity_date , count(*) [count]
FROM (SELECT A.lead_id, A.primary_attribute_value_id, T.name, A.activity_date
FROM marketo_tg.lead_activities A, marketo_tg.lead_activity_types T
WHERE T.name IN ('Send Email', 'Email Delivered', 'Open Email', 'Click Email', 'Unsubscribe Email') AND A.activity_type_id=T.id 
GROUP BY A.lead_id, A.primary_attribute_value_id, T.name, A.activity_date) A, marketo_tg.emails E
WHERE A.primary_attribute_value_id = E.id AND E.name LIKE '%Bounceback%'
GROUP BY email, activity_t, subject, A.activity_date)b
GROUP BY email, subject, activity_date
```